# Workaround for datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(dateFrom) in numba?

Tags: python, numba

Using [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/), not everything that's possible in usual Python scripts can be used.

I would like to convert an `int` to a `datetime` object. In usual Python, this can be done via:

```
dateFrom = 0
a = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(dateFrom)
print (a)
> 1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

Using numba this leads to an error:

```
import numba as nb
import datetime

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def abc():

    dateFrom = 0
    a = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(dateFrom)
    return a

print(abc())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/venv/numba/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-12-0ded7f14df2a>", line 1, in <module>
    print(abc())
  File "/home/user/venv/numba/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 401, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "/home/user/venv/numba/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 344, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)
  File "/home/user/venv/numba/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/six.py", line 668, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'datetime' of type Module(<module 'datetime' from '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/datetime.py'>)
File "<ipython-input-11-a989c5d8d15a>", line 8:
def abc():
    <source elided>
    dateFrom = 0
    a = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(dateFrom)
    ^

....

To see Python/NumPy features supported by the latest release of Numba visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html
and
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html
```

How can I get a properly printed datetime-alike object when using numba?

Comment: `datetime` is a python module that isn't duplicated in `numba`.  Does turning  off the `nopython` command help?

Comment: turning it off would help, but with this I would loose the tremendous speed advantage of numba for this function. So I would like to have both: speed and the comfort of real datetime values

Comment: But real datetime objects are python objects.  Does numba handle `datetime64` dtypes?

Comment: Using `a = np.array([dateFrom]).astype(np.int).astype('datetime64[s]')` unfortunately leads to a `Invalid use of BoundFunction(array.astype for array(int64, 1d, C)) with parameters (Function(<class 'int'>))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The experts from `numba` gave me the solution:

a callback to the python interpreter is possible using `with objmode()`. Details: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/withobjmode.html

Example:

```
from numba import njit, objmode
from numba.typed import List
import datetime


@njit
def foo(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            with objmode():
                print(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(i))
        # do compute here


l = List()
for i in range(10000):
    l.append(i)
foo(l)
```